# What is a word for "not well studied"

Tags: single-word-requests

or "not well understood".
(as applied to a culture or topic)
My mind is slipping on it. Not 'elusive', more that it just hasn't been well-examined.
Thanks!

Comment: You're probably looking for an un-negated word, so uncharted, unexplored, underconsidered etc. are out?

Comment: I'm thinking of a word that complements 'esoteric'...but which somehow describes the nature of the subject (if a subject or culture can be introverted, say)...

Comment: it is "inaccessible"? It "resists study"?

Comment: Perhaps "obscure"?

Comment: A culture can be described as "isolated"

Comment: In the same vein as "obscure" would be "arcane".

Comment: In the same family as abstruse, esoteric, what about  "recondite"?

Comment: Often if a writer has reason to point out that a potential field of study is "not well understood", he'll also want to throw in his own value judgement - so it's a ***neglected*** field.

Comment: Overlooked, ignored.

Answer (score 12):

I've seen variations on the following:

- little studied
- under-examined
- open field
- unexplored

These are often combined with *relatively* so the reviewers don't carp.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking for single words, "cloudy", "nebulous", "blear", "obscure"

> blear - obscure to the view or imagination [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blear)
>
> nebulous - unclear, vague, or ill-defined [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nebulous)
>
> cloudy - uncertain; nuclear [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cloudy)

If you are asking for phrases, then you have quite a few good choices

> - not completely understood.
> - not fully elucidated.
> - needing further research.
> - not fully clarified.

Examples from scientific papers:

- "Exact mechanisms responsible for this kind of endocrinopathy have not been completely clarified." [Autoimmune Diseases](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=9CkW-vE51xYC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=the+mechanism+has+not+been+completely&source=bl&ots=OPin4uab7l&sig=4aRiPX3H3eEhzeqmdLAA5XXlgPM&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=-dp8VIL1J8ehgwT6i4KwDQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAw)
- "The mechanism of pain has not yet been fully understood."
- "The mechanism of cerebral uptake has not been completely elucidated." [Nuclear Medicine](http://www.nucmedtutorials.com/dwradiopharm/rad9.html)
- "Its exact mechanism of action needs further research."

Answer (score 2):

Author I'm working with (ELL) used "understudied" but I'm not sure that's a good idea since "understudy" is well known with a completely unrelated meaning.

> **Understudied (adj):** An understudied subject has not been studied as much as it should be or as much as you would expect.
>
> Example: The terrapin is a surprisingly understudied species.
>
>  [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/understudied)

Comment: Hello, Elsa, welcome to EL&U! This is a good option, thanks! See [good answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for further info. I have suggested adding a quote and link to a dictionary to your post, but you can feel free to  roll it back if it is not fitting. Please give some time to take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't done so. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

More than one word comes to mind, but I am not sure if they are what you're looking for. From the world of medicine, "of unknown etiology" and "idiopathic," http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=3892. From literature and reviewing, recherche, with an accent over the final e, http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recherch%C3%A9

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single word for "not well studied", but there are adverbs such as *little*, *poorly* and *relatively* that are more commonly used in place of “not well”.

- little-known / little known
- relatively obscure
- poorly studied
- [underresearched](https://www.yourdictionary.com/underresearched) / under-researched

> *Cystic fibrosis: how to recognize this **little-known** illness*

> *In short, this **relatively obscure** plant is far more interesting and scientifically valuable than anyone might have guessed.*

> *Institutional racism is shown to account for significant continuities in the approach of universities to race equality, yet race in higher education is an **under-researched** area.*

> *Ecological implications of recently discovered and **poorly studied** sources of energy for the growth of true fungi especially in extreme environments*