# How to say something is under-explored?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am writing a proposal on a rising area, which just starts to attract attention recently. I want to say there was not a lot work on this before, and thus under-explored.

Comment: See possible duplicated, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211355/what-is-a-word-for-not-well-studied/211360#211360

Comment: @Xanne — No. None of these are common in a scientific context.

Comment: What is the area? The context is relevant to your choice of words.

Comment: @David On the contrary, David, many of them are directly from a scientific context. You should read more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word you're looking for is [**underdeveloped**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underdeveloped):

> **2** : having a relatively low economic level of industrial production and standard of living (as from lack of capital)
> // *underdeveloped* nations
>
> // Founded in 1989 with an initial $50,000 investment, Chesapeake focused on drilling in *underdeveloped* areas of Oklahoma and Texas.
> — *CBS News*, "Chesapeake Energy, Oklahoma "fracking" pioneer, files for bankruptcy," 29 June 2020

This would be the *before* state of something that is now "on the rise" in terms of attention and, well, development.

---

Of course, if you're really talking about exploration, the actual word would be [*unexplored*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unexplored), and it would refer to parts of an area: "The area remains largely unexplored."

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I guess unexplored is a good word for this. Just curious, is underexplored even an english word?

Comment: @NanWang *Underexplored* doesn't have an entry in Merriam-Webster, but it does exist in [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/definition/underexplored). To me, it sounds strange—even though I understand the meaning. However, saying that something is a "rising area" that has not had a lot of "work" does not connote a lack of exploration, but a lack of development. The geography has been found, just not made use of.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: I wouldn’t use this in an academic sense. It certainly isn’t used in the biological sciences.

Answer (score 1):

*neglected* is also a useful word to describe this. It signifies that the theme exists but has not hitherto attracted much attention. In this way it differs from *undiscovered*, which does not suit your purpose. Here is a good example: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/16332979/

Comment: The connotation is that researchers could have addressed the topic but chose not to. This may be suitable for the example you give but sounds odd in most other contexts. Was quantum mechanics neglected in the 19th century? Was CRISPR gene editing neglected a few years ago?

Answer (score 1):

@Anton has a good answer, supported by an example, but in practice it may be more politic to avoid a term that may be taken to reflect badly on others in the field. The banner on that link gives an alternative that one could use:

> **Emerging**

As in:

> “Covid-19 is an emerging…”

(But for goodness sake, don’t copy “situation”. “Area” is fine.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But the area is not emerging, but not treated very seriously. Maybe I should describe the context more clearly next time.