# Word for "Unresearched/Untested and therefore potentially dangerous"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a word for this? E.g.

> The [unresearched/untested and therefore potentially dangerous] nature of brain implants may delay their becoming popular as people will be reluctant to use them.

It seems hard to shorten this while keeping both the untested element and the dangerous element. E.g. potentially adverse isn't quite specific enough about the lack of testing. Words similar to untested or unresearched (obscure?) won't do because they leave out the danger. [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211355/what-is-a-word-for-not-well-studied#211360) almost answers my query but not quite. I have searched synonyms for both "untested" and "dangerous"/"hazardous" alone but cannot find an instance of them being intertwined. Ideally I would hope to find a way of saying this in three or fewer words, with fewer being better - I think brevity sounds better here. Something I can put before "nature" is ideal but I may change the sentence.

Comment: Everything **untested** is both potentially dangerous and potentially harmless or good. Why add potentially dangerous?

Comment: To emphasize that it IS potentially dangerous - I need negative connotations here. Just untested is less cause for concern and more cause for intrigue. I am trying to bias this text.

Comment: Also why does it say "cigien" edited my question - but they didn't seem to change anything? I'm new here and I don't quite understand that.

Comment: A member named Cigien corrected a typo by Duo...

Comment: Ah, right. Makes sense.

Comment: If you click on the link above the editor usercard that says "edited ... ago", you can see the [revision history](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/586830/revisions), which shows a side by side diff of the text, as well as the reason for the edit (assuming the editor leaves a descriptive message).

Comment: Safety and effectiveness are too different things.

Comment: "experimental" comes to mind, but the meaning of "potentially dangerous" is more of a connotation than a part of the core meaning

Comment: Simply say _dangerous_. In security, qualifications are complications. If you say it's dangerous, they've been warned; _dangerous_ **means** 'potentially dangerous'. The modal is built in.

Comment: @JohnLawler But it seems like he also wants to emphasize *why* it's considered dangerous (as opposed to a situation where the tests show it's dangerous). I don't think there's a single word that encompasses this.